# Make properly namespaced cython submodules

Tags: python, build, cython, git-submodules

Let's say that I have a fairly standard python project foo, with directory structure

```
pyproject.toml
src\
    foo\
        bar.py
        bar2.py
```

Then, when I build/install the project, I get a module foo, with submodules bar and bar2, e.g., I can do

```
from foo.bar import Bar
from foo.bar2 import Bar2
```

Now, say that I want to replace bar and bar2 with a cython versions. My new directory structure is

```
pyproject.toml
setup.py
src\
    foo\
        bar.pxd
        bar.pyx
        bar2.pxd
        bar2.pyx
```

with bar containing

```
from bar cimport *
```

(and similarly for bar2) and setup.py containing

```
Extension(
    "bar",
    ["src/foo/bar.pyx"]
)
```

(and similarly for bar2). The problem is that when I build/install this, I get a top level bar2 project, not foo.bar2. If I change the name in the extension to "foo.bar2", then the compilation breaks due to the cimport line, and if I change that line, everything breaks. Is there a proper way to do this, or do I need to have a separate cython module (or subfolder w/setup.py for each cython submodule)?